Explicitly, where is 2-loop pure gravity divergent?
I don't quite understand why 2-loop pure graviton scattering is divergent. It looks UV finite to me when I naively compute the superficial divergence $$D=dL-2I\tag{1}$$ for $d=4, L=2, I=5$.
Consider the 1PI diagram built from 3-vertices below, we have $D=-2$

and the integral would look something like
$$\begin{equation}
\int\frac{(d^4k)}{(2\pi)^4}\int\frac{(d^4l)}{(2\pi)^4}(-ig)^4\frac{i\mathcal{P}_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}}{k^2+i\epsilon}\frac{i\mathcal{P}_{\dots}}{l^2+i\epsilon}\frac{i\mathcal{P}_{\dots}}{(P_{in}-k)^2+i\epsilon}\frac{i\mathcal{P}_{\dots}}{(P_{out}-l)^2+i\epsilon}\frac{i\mathcal{P}_{\dots}}{(k-l)^2+i\epsilon}(2\pi)^4\delta^4(P_{in}-P_{out})\propto\int\frac{k^8}{k^{10}}=\Lambda^{-2}
\end{equation}\tag{2}$$
where I am suppressing the indices structure with "$\dots$" for simplicity of typing the integral.
which is looks UV finite.
Am doing something wrong with my calculation? Where exactly do the UV divergences come from?

Just a note, why do you have 5 occurrences of every index here? That makes the numerator of your expression wildly ambiguous even if that's not the crux of the problem.

Sorry, I just copy pasted it so I wouldn't have to write all of it out explicitly. Should I replace them with a squiggly?

Well if the numerator is not too important you could use the $mathcal{N}(..)$ like $\mathcal{N}(..)$ as a place holder, just remember to show whatever the net index should be after all the contractions take place. It's just a side note is all and doesn't really bare much on the question itself.

Okay thanks! I have just edited the question. :)

Do you understand the arguments about why irrelevant operators are non-renormalizable? If not I'd review those. If so, then do you know that general relativity has an infinite tower of irrelevant operators? If you expand $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}/M_{\rm Pl}$, then the Lagrangian is (schematically) $(\partial h)^2 + M_{\rm Pl}^{-1} h (\partial h)^2 + \cdots$. The irrelevant operators mean GR is going to be non renormalizable.

I understand that it is non-renormalizable due to the coupling having negative mass dimensions. But if the integral itself converges and is finite, then we don't need to renormalize right?

@PhysicsStudent101 If you understand the first statement, you would understand the second statement can't be true.

@Andrew I'm lost now. We "need" renormalization when rescaling theories to calculate physical parameters at a specific momentum scale. Ie: we can use a single effective diagram to calculate the sum of the perturbative diagrams to some cutoff rather than tediously calculating order by order. If the gravitational integrals in a correct finite theory (not the one above) are convergent to all orders, can't we just brute force and go order by order using the bare coupling? After all, the gravitational interaction is already pinned to the length scale set by $M_{pl}$ before canonical normalization.

@PhysicsStudent101 "I understand that it is non-renormalizable due to the coupling having negative mass dimensions." --> The reason this is true is because of superficial degree of divergence arguments that show that irrelevant operators will generate more and more divergences if you try to renormalize them. Gravity has irrelevant operators. So that should tell you that the calculation in your question couldn't be correct.

@Andrew Okay yes, I agree. The calculation in the question is incorrect for that reason as pointed out in the answer below. My second comment for not needing renormalization, was referring to if we had a correct theory that is finite and convergent to all orders. Apologies, I should have elaborated.

@PhysicsStudent101 It's ok, I'm being a bit snarky. You would still need to do "renormalization" even if integrals were finite, in the following sense. We say the "mass" of a particle is the coefficient of the quadratic term in the Lagrangian because that's how things work in a free theory. But really the "mass" is something we observe, and in an interacting theory the thing observed as "mass" is not the coefficient of the quadratic term, it's some quantity made by summing that coefficient with various loop integrals in the self energy. So even without divergences, interactions change the mass

But you are quite right that divergences wouldn't arise if the loops were finite and everyone would feel much better about things being well defined.

Well, in perturbative gravity, each interactions term contains 2 derivatives$^1$, so the Feynman rule for a vertex has 2 momentum factors in the numerator that raise the superficial degree of divergence $D$, i.e. OP's eq. (1) is modified.

$^1$ See e.g. eq. (4) in my Phys.SE answer here.

Ah I see, I didn't take that into account. So when the indices are contracted, the resulting $[\mathcal{P}_{\dots}]$ has momentum dimensions of $[k]^4$ for 2-loop?

Sorry, just saw your edit. So it should have been $[k]^6$ for the 2-loop integral. and also $D$ should be modified to be $D=dL-2I+2V$. Should I make an edit to include this correction above in the question section?
